# How to crawl only two pre-defined pages, but they scrape different items?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a site driven by some user input. For example, the user gives me the pid of a product and a name, and a separate program will launch the spider, gather the data, and return it to the user.

However, the only information I want are product and person which are found in two links to an xml. If I know these two links and the pattern, how do I build the callback to parse the different items?

For example, if I have these two Items defined:

```
class PersonItem(Item):
     name = Field()
     ...

class ProductItem(Item):
     pid = Field()
     ...
```

And I know their links have pattern:

```
www.example.com/person/*<name_of_person>*/person.xml
www.example.com/*<product_pid>*/product.xml
```

Then my spider would look something like this:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
     name = "myspider"

     # simulated given by user
     pid = "4545-fw"
     person = "bob"

     allowed_domains = ["http://www.example.com"]
     start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/person/%s/person.xml'%person, 'http://www.example.com/%s/product.xml'%pid]

     def parse(self, response):

          # Not sure here if scrapping person or item
```

I know that I can define rules too using `Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor())` and then giving the person and product each its own parse callback. However, I'm not sure how they apply here since I think rules are meant for crawling deeper, whereas I only need to scrape the surface level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be retro-active you could put your logic in `parse()`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if 'person.xml' in response.url:
        item = PersonItem()
    elif 'product.xml' in response.url:
        item = ProductItem()
    else:
        raise Exception('Could not determine item type')
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to be pro-active you could override `start_requests()`:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    pid = "4545-fw"
    person = "bob"

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = (
            ('http://www.example.com/person/%s/person.xml' % self.person, PersonItem),
            ('http://www.example.com/%s/product.xml' % self.pid, ProductItem),
        )
        for url, cls in start_urls:
            yield Request(url, meta=dict(cls=cls))

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['cls']()
```

Comment: Yeah, I considered just looking for keywords in a link to determine which item to create. For this particular example it will work, but I was wondering if there was a more generic way of doing this.

Comment: I wouldn't override `parse` in `XMLFeedSpider` unless you have to, but yes, it should work.